# Codeigniter: Check where model is loaded from?

Tags: codeigniter, model, load, where-clause

I'm having the strangest thing ever right now.

I "disabled" a model because i don't need to access it ever again. I did so by echoing out an error string in the __construct() and right after that die(). That way i would notice if i ever loaded the model, even by mistake, which should never happen. Alright?

The problem is, the model is not loaded ANYWHERE in the entire project, but it still gets loaded for some reason. It's not auto loaded, that's for sure.

Is it possible to track down where a model is loaded? Like which line it happens etc?

Comment: If you want to remove a model, why don't you just delete the file?

Comment: Never hurts to keep the code, i might need it in the future.

Comment: That's why you use a revision control system like git or svn.  You can delete the file, and then if you need it again, go back in the history and get it.

Comment: Some day, good sir, i will start using git! But for now, i don't have the time or the motivation. It seems quite complex for such a system, is it?

Comment: The first time you lose an edit, you will have had plenty of time where you could have saved it.  While `git` has piles of complexity, the [philosophical basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) are straightforward and the mechanics are [simple](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch02.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the model, add this:

```
print_r (debug_backtrace());
```

There is also PHP's `debug_print_backtrace()` which will format it better:

```
function __construct__ ()
{
    debug_print_backtrace();
}
```

Comment: After all this time, how did i miss this function? This did indeed help me. Thanks!